# display notification whether the application is running or in the background

Tags: android, notifications

I  want to display a notification to the user whether my appalication is running or not This is the notification code I have tried to implement.
A notification is displayed only when the app is running. But, i want to display this notification even when my app isn't running . How can I achieve this?

```
public void Notification(String s)
{
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

        int icon = R.drawable.notification_icon;
        CharSequence tickerText = "Ready for Play time."; // ticker-text
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence contentTitle = "Play Time";
        CharSequence contentText = "Your match is at "+s;
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this,ScheldueNotification .class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        // and this

        mNotificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.vibrate = new long[] { 0, 100, 200, 300 };
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

}
```

Comment: You want to show notification when your app is in background, right?

Comment: No. my app is not already running. but wanna show notification.

Comment: For that, you will have to make use of `service`.

Comment: Can you show me some example codes? Please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create WakefulBroadcastReceiver for partial wake lock ,if you are not doing this, add this to your project-

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create and invoke this function in another class which will extend `Service` class. After that start service from your activity which will send notification.Try this code:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    NotificationManager manager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {   
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {          
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        Notification(String s);
    }

    public void Notification(String s)
    {
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

        int icon = R.drawable.notification_icon;
        CharSequence tickerText = "Ready for Play time.";
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence contentTitle = "Play Time";
        CharSequence contentText = "Your match is at "+s;
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this,ScheldueNotification .class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);


        mNotificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.vibrate = new long[] { 0, 100, 200, 300 };
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

}
```

Write this code in your activity which will invoke service .

```
private Intent myIntent;
myIntent = new Intent(myActivity.this,MyService.class);
startService(myIntent);
```